# How to combine Valid constraint with nullable embedded form

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to combine the ability to validate an embedded form if included in the request payload with skipping this validation if not included.

My use case is the following.

I sent to my controller the following json including the resource Campaign and the subresource Article.

```
{
   "campaign": {
       "name": "New campaign",
       "article": {
           "title": "How to develope faster",
           "summary": "This is a <b>summary</b>"
       }
   }
}
```

This is processed by a Symfony form with the following validation:

```
AppBundle\Document\Campaign:
  properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank:
            message: 'campaign.validation.name.not_blank'
        - Length:
            min: 1
            max: 300
            minMessage: 'campaign.validation.name.length.min'
            maxMessage: 'campaign.validation.name.length.max'
    article:
        - Valid: ~

AppBundle\Document\Article:
  properties:
    title:
        - NotBlank:
            message: 'article.validation.title.not_blank'
        - Length:
            min: 20
            max: 300
            minMessage: 'article.validation.title.length.min'
            maxMessage: 'article.validation.title.length.max'
```

The Forms look like:

```
class CampaignFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new FieldToModelTransformer($options['manager'], 'slug');

        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('article', new ArticleFormType());

        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('brand', 'text', [
                'invalid_message' => 'campaign.validation.brand.invalid'
            ])->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Document\Campaign',
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'campaign';
    }
}

class ArticleFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Document\Article',
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'article';
    }
}
```

So the problem is if I set the Valid contraint in the subform, the validation system always pass the validation on the subresource even if it is not passed. So this request will fail:

```
{
    "campaign": {
        "name": "New campaign"
    }
}
```

I would like to achive the following behaviour:

- If article payload has data then validate it
- If article is empty or null then do not validate the subresource

How is the cleanest way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Where does the validation fail? Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what is happening.

My controller is a standard one creating the form, submitting the request, etc... and if article is not in the json it does not get autopopulated automatically so it is null in the request until the form submitting.

I have 3 data sets for testing (Scenario 1):

Test 1:

```
{
    "campaign": {
        "name": "New campaign",
        "startDate": "2012-01-01",
        "endDate": "2012-02-01"
    }
}
```

Test 2:

```
{
    "campaign": {
        "article": {
            "title": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Test 3:

```
{
    "campaign": {
        "article": {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Whatever valid value"
        }
    }
}
```

Without changing the forms nor validation this is the result:

- Test 1: Validation on article turns on and throws not blank on article.title
- Test 2: Validation on article turns on and throws not blank on article.title
- Test 3: Validation on article turns on and throws not blank on article.title

The key is modifying the form field article and adding to it the option required false:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new FieldToModelTransformer($options['manager'], 'slug');

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('article', new ArticleFormType(), [
                'required' => false
            ]);

        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('brand', 'text', [
                'invalid_message' => 'campaign.validation.brand.invalid'
            ])->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        );
    }
```

This way executing the same tree tests the results are (Scenario 2):

- Test 1: Validation on article is not turning on
- Test 2: Validation on article is not turning on even passing the title to empty or null
- Test 3: Validation on article turns on and throws not blank on article.title

So, summarising I need to set **required false** on the embedded form to be optional BUT If I pass a the embedded object with properties equal to empty or null it is automatically cleaned up.

I expected Test 2 of scenario 2 to turn on the validation on title but it is not due to this cleaning of null properties.

I mean, I expected this result:

- Test 1: Validation on article is not turning on
- **Test 2: Validation on article turns on and throws not blank on article.title**
- Test 3: Validation on article turns on and throws not blank on article.title

This behaviour does make sense but I didn't expected it as default one so maybe the documentation on Valid constraint could be more explicit or maybe I am wrong about this assumption.